# How can I code in C++ with the same indentation style both in Vi and Emacs?

Tags: c++, vim, emacs, vi, indentation

How can two developers work on a same C++ code base such that they can work transparently ? 
Is there any common indentation style for C++ code such that once it is established, the two developers can produce code with the same indentation level.

I have found Emacs very aggressive for Indentation, it tries to force its way, while Vi is pretty forgiving. But the emacs styles(mixed tabs and spaces) are not that much friendly to Vim.

Comment: It would be easier if you define what you want both editors to do. Then users of each could tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Get Emacs to do what you want.**

From my ~/.emacs file:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (local-set-key "\C-h" 'backward-delete-char)
  ;; this will make sure spaces are used instead of tabs
  (setq tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode 'nil)
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'statement-case-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'case-label 0)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-open 0)
)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'nroff-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'tcl-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I was looking for.  
I just have to find the equivalent indentation rules for Vim counterpart.

Comment: I am googling for cinoptions(in vim) for the equivalent style. I hope I can land on the equivalent indentation style.

Answer (score 7):

What I did when I managed a small team was I used a check-in hook that called the BSD program "indent", which forced everybody's code into the same indentation style.  See [Enforcing a coding style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284259/enforcing-a-coding-style)

Comment: This approach should be preferred much more, I think.